# GCP splitting commitment in updating state for a long time

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have purchased 2GB memory in the GCP commitmented use discounts. I try to split the commitment to 1GB each but it shows fail message: "Splitting commitment "commitment-memory-1" Commitment 'commitment-memory-1' is in UPDATING state and cannot be merged or split".

[image]

[image]

Now in the billing console I only can see 1GB active commitment. The other 1GB was disappear. Is anyone know how to change the commitment from UPDATING state to active?

[image]

[image]

I try to contact GCP billing support and they don't know what to do and asking me to purchase the tech support package to solve this problem

Comment: We cannot look up or do anything with your account. You will need to open a Google Cloud support ticket.

Comment: @JohnHanley is there any way can open a support ticket? My project only had Basic (billing-only) support. I try to contact them but they said they don't know how help.

Comment: Go here and sign up for support: https://cloud.google.com/support?hl=en